# Logout by session id and do not delete authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to refactor my application to add a functionality to run the app in some browser tabs. 
I would like to make a different session for every tab/window (for the same user) and create a docker container for every session. So far it is all working. When I sign out from one tab the app stops its own docker container **but** it clears authentication for all sessions. 
Do you have any idea how to prevent clearing this authentication?

This is a part of my "configure" method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {           
/.../
http
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler)
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .clearAuthentication(false);
/.../
}
```

LogoutHandler:

```
@Component
```

public class LogoutHandler extends SecurityContextLogoutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

```
@Inject
UserService userService;

@Inject
Environment environment;

@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (authentication != null) {
        String sessionId = ((WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getSessionId();

        if (sessionId != null) {
            userService.logout(sessionId);
            response.sendRedirect(ShinyProxyApplication.getContextPath(environment));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: how does your logoutHandler look like?

Comment: I added my logoutHandler code